# Validate AMP for Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

I followed all the instructions to set up amp on my blog. When I validate AMP I´ve got some errors like:

```
The tag 'amp-position-observer' requires including the 'amp-position-observer' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
3
659
The tag 'amp-sidebar' requires including the 'amp-sidebar' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
3
27804
The tag 'amp-social-share' requires including the 'amp-social-share' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
3
27967
The tag 'amp-social-share' requires including the 'amp-social-share' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
3
28041
The tag 'amp-social-share' requires including the 'amp-social-share' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
3
28115
The tag 'amp-social-share' requires including the 'amp-social-share' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
3
28193
The tag 'amp-social-share' requires including the 'amp-social-share' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
3
35976
The tag 'amp-animation' requires including the 'amp-animation' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
3
36025
The tag 'amp-animation extension .json script' requires including the 'amp-animation' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
6
28
The tag 'amp-animation' requires including the 'amp-animation' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
6
77
The tag 'amp-animation extension .json script' requires including the 'amp-animation' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
9
210
The tag 'amp-social-share' requires including the 'amp-social-share' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
9
373
The tag 'amp-social-share' requires including the 'amp-social-share' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
9
447
The tag 'amp-social-share' requires including the 'amp-social-share' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
9
521
The tag 'amp-social-share' requires including the 'amp-social-share' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
9
621
The tag 'amp-social-share' requires including the 'amp-social-share' extension JavaScript. Debug. Learn more.
9
7975
The parent tag of tag 'amp-accordion extension .js script' is 'body', but it can only be 'head'. Debug. Learn more.
10
0
The parent tag of tag 'amp-position-observer extension .js script' is 'body', but it can only be 'head'. Debug. Learn more.
11
0
The parent tag of tag 'amp-animation extension .js script' is 'body', but it can only be 'head'. Debug. Learn more.
12
0
The parent tag of tag 'amp-social-share extension .js script' is 'body', but it can only be 'head'. Debug. Learn more.
13
0
The parent tag of tag 'amp-sidebar extension .js script' is 'body', but it can only be 'head'. Debug. Learn more.
14
0
The parent tag of tag 'amphtml engine v0.js script' is 'body', but it can only be 'head'. Debug. Learn more.
```

What Should I do ?

I tried to change pluging and themes but I have nout found these king of errors through internet.

Comment: Have you checked each "Learn more" link yet? You may find hints/instructions in every link telling you how to properly implement each feature. Also, when seeking debugging help you need to show some code for us to provide some actual advice (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.)

Comment: Hi, tks for helping me. yes, I did read the documentation then I read that I have to put this on header: <script async custom-element="amp-position-observer" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-position-observer-0.1.js"></script> but it did not work. also I put that code on amp advanced settings (there is an area called header). It did not work eigther.